# How to restart a tee branch (WARN no codec_data in h264 caps)?

Tags: gstreamer

I have a pipeline on an IMX with 2 cameras as stream source, an image compositor, and several outputs linked on a tee, one on UDP, one in a filesink, and a last one in an hlssink for streaming through a http server. Here is the pipe :

```
imxv4l2videosrc device=/dev/video2 ! queue ! pa_compositor.sink_1
imxv4l2videosrc device=/dev/video3 ! queue ! pa_compositor.sink_2
imxg2dcompositor background-color=0x000000
sink_1::width=400 sink_1::height=300
sink_2::width=400 sink_2::height=300
queue ! video/x-raw,width=800,height=600 ! imxipuvideotransform ! imxvpuenc_h264 bitrate=3000 !
tee
pa_tee. ! queue name=mp4_queue ! h264parse ! mp4mux ! filesink location=/home/root/pa_camera.mp4
pa_tee. ! queue ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink playlist-root=http://192.168.44.110/hls 
pa_tee. ! queue ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=192.168.44.63
```

I need to start/stop output on a given tee branch, say mp4mux for instance.
So far, when user wants to disable mp4mux, I simply send an EOS on  mp4_queue sink. This way I can retrieve destination file /home/root/pa_camera.mp4, it is valid.

The problem occurs when I want to restart the tee branch. I have tried to set state tee branch elements in GST_STATE_NULL then GST_STATE_PLAYING. I then get the following erros in logs :

```
WARN       codecparsers_h264 gsth264parser.c:1691:gst_h264_parser_parse_slice_hdr: couldn't find associated picture parameter set with id: 0
WARN       qtmux gstqtmux.c:3093:gst_qt_mux_video_sink_set_caps:<video_mp4mux_1> no codec_data in h264 caps
WARN       qtmux gstqtmux.c:3245:gst_qt_mux_video_sink_set_caps:<video_mp4mux_1> pad video_0 refused caps video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, parsed=(boolean)true, width=(int)800, height=(int)600, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, framerate=(fraction)30/1
```

I have also tried to send EOS through a blocking probe added on tee source, and to set tee elements to NULL/PLAYING state in an event probe on filesink, as suggested in gstreamer API documentation. Same result: the branch cannot be restarted.

What is it that I'm missing ?

Thanks,

etienne

---

Comment: I guess you want to finish recording of one file and start another.. what about - fitrst block src pad on mp4_queue, send eos on the queue(this will flush the buffers into filesink and properly ends it), when you see eos on filesink you set to NULL all the elements, then set to playing and ublock.. read through [this](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/manual/html/section-dynamic-pipelines.html) and maybe I missed something

Comment: I have also tried with a blocking probe, as described in the link you provided. With the same effect : I can not restart the branch

Comment: this is too complicated stuff - try to ask on IRC

Answer (score 0):

H264 in AVC format  should have a codec_data field in its caps. Does it have in the first time you run?

If you try: `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc num-buffers=100 ! x264enc ! "video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc" ! fakesink -v` you should see the codec_data printed in the caps.

I'd start by checking the caps for the first time and if it changes on the second time you link the pad. Could be an issue at your encoder or h264parse.